# issue setting gradient colour the Navigation bar Xcode 12

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to set a gradient colour background for my navigation bar. Code is like so:

```
extension UINavigationBar {

func setGradientBackground(to navController: UINavigationController) {

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    var bounds = navController.navigationBar.bounds
    bounds.size.height += UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
    gradient.frame = bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.init(red: 85, green: 181, blue: 180, alpha: 1), UIColor.init(red: 76, green: 144, blue: 172, alpha: 1)]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)

    if let image = getImageFrom(gradientLayer: gradient) {
        navController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    }
}
```

And then make it an image:

```
    func getImageFrom(gradientLayer:CAGradientLayer) -> UIImage? {
    var gradientImage:UIImage?
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.frame.size)
    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        gradientLayer.render(in: context)
        gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero, resizingMode: .stretch)
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return gradientImage
}
```

viewDidLoad:

```
        navigationController!.navigationBar.setGradientBackground(to: self.navigationController!)
```

But the result is not the colours I choose is only white.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYe1n.png)
Is anyone know what is going wrong ?

Comment: You are not setting the relative locations of the colors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I apply CAGradientLayer to a UINavigationController background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55429340/how-can-i-apply-cagradientlayer-to-a-uinavigationcontroller-background)

Comment: How I setting locations of the colors?